# Cypress: Trouble trying to replicate cy.origin AAD login solution on a non-local website when login is triggered automatically

Tags: authentication, cypress, cypress-custom-commands

I'Ve been having the following problem while trying to replicate the [Azure Active Directory Authentication](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/end-to-end-testing/azure-active-directory-authentication) for a non-local website that calls the Microsoft loging page directly. I've been told to use the cy.visit clause instead of the cy.origin clause as we are being automatically redirected. Even though I am using this method, I am getting the following error message:

AADSTS9000411: The request is not properly formatted. The parameter 'iframe-request-id' is duplicated.

After a time, I also get this error:

AADSTS90015: Requested query string is too long.

Now, I have added the following tags in the cypress.config.js file:

experimentalModifyObstructiveThirdPartyCode: true,
experimentalOriginDependencies: true

As far as I understand it, these two tags as used to address, amongst other things, frame busting issues.

Here is the code I tried to do the login:

function loginViaAAD(url, username, password) {
cy.visit(url).then(($username, $password) => {

```
    cy.get('input[type="email"]').type(username, {
        log: false
    });
    cy.get('input[type="submit"]').click().then(($password) => {
        cy.get('input[type="password"]').type(password, {
            log: false
        });

        cy.get('input[type="submit"]').click();
        cy.get('#idBtn_Back').click()
    })
})
  
// Login to your AAD tenant. (Old cy.origin code from the exampke listed above).
/*cy.origin(
  "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  {
    args: {
      username,
      password
    }
  },
  ({ username,password }) => {
    cy.get('input[type="email"]').type(username, {
      log: false
    })
    cy.get('input[type="submit"]').click().then(($password) => {
        cy.get('input[type="password"]').type(password, {
          log: false
        })
        cy.get('input[type="submit"]').click()
      })
  }
)*/
// Ensure Microsoft has redirected us back to the sample app with our logged in user.
cy.url().should("equal", url)
cy.get("#welcome-div").should(
  "contain",
  `Welcome ${Cypress.env("aad_username")}!`
)
```

}

Cypress.Commands.add("loginToAAD", (url, username, password) => {
cy.session(
`${username}`,
() => {
const log = Cypress.log({
displayName: "Azure Active Directory Login",
message: [ `Authenticating | ${username}`],
// @ts-ignore
autoEnd: false
})

```
    log.snapshot("before")

    loginViaAAD(url, username, password)

    log.snapshot("after")
    log.end()
},
{
validate: () => {
    // this is a very basic form of session validation 
    cy.visit(url)
    cy.get("#welcome-div").should(
    "contain",
    `Welcome ${Cypress.env("aad_username")}!`)
    }
})
```

})

As far as I can tell, It should work, but as mentionned with the errors above, it is not.

Now, perhaps the issue comes from the fact I am trying this login method on a already deployed site that might have mechanisms in place that does not allow for this login method. Are there any avenues I should be exploring to addresses the errors I listed above?

On the side I also trying to get a login token wih the following code:

Cypress.Commands.add('loginAAD2', (tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, username, password) => {
return cy
.request({
method: 'POST',
url: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/oauth2/token`,
form: true,
body: {
grant_type: 'password',
tenant: tenantId,
client_id: clientId,
client_secret: clientSecret,
username: username,
password: password,
resource: clientId,
},
})
.then((response) => {
sessionStorage.setItem('access_token', response.body.access_token);
});
});

Here, I am assuing that I need to ask the IT guys to generate a clientid / client secret so that I am able to receive a token from MS (Assuming this method would still even work)?

Thanks in advance!